# min-width in page body not working

Tags: html, css

I have set a minimum width of 767px on my website to avoid everything to be shrunk when viewing the website on a smartphone.
The issue is that is that it doesn't seem to be taken into consideration (see screenshot below)
Any idea why?
Many thanks

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 767px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.004);
    background: url('../images/background-produits.jpg')no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.38;
    color: rgb(71, 64, 50);
}
```

Comment: I see a horizontal scrollbar when I reduce the width <767px, which is what you should expect when setting a min-width (users won't like it though, nobody likes horizontal scrollbars!). What behaviour are you expecting, cause it seems to work fine to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a lot of things positioned absolutely. For that to work correctly you need to have them contained in an item with relative positioning. Yep, even the body tag, apparently.

```
body {position: relative}
```

Answer (score -1):

You also need to give it `width: 100%` only then `min-width` kicks in