# min-width not working on the entire page

Tags: html, css

On my website I've set a min-width of 760px in my body tag. For some reason it only seems to be applied to the navigation menu at the top of the page. The tire picture, facebook buttons and footer all seemed to be center based on the size of my mobile phone screen (see screenshot), not 760px. How come? Many thanks

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro';
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 1.38;
    color: #000000;
    min-height: 500px;
    min-width: 760px;
    }
```

Comment: Play with `display: inline-block` on the nav menu, to force breaking if screen size gets smaller. Perhaps you also have to change `min-width` and `max-width` or `width`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [min-width in page body not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238378/min-width-in-page-body-not-working)

Comment: It was a different problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting the website not to be responsive? Or responsive so that it all fits inside the view port? The reason why your footer with all the social links and your contact details are centered regardless of screen size is that it always centers itself because of your `text-align:center` for  Facebook container. this is doing it for the text as well, because it is inheriting the style on default.

Just try setting the width you have for the body into your footer container and using good ol'`margin:auto`  to keep it centered